# Use Arelle web service with php

Tags: xbrl, arelle

I used Arelle web service for getting fact list of xbrl files with the CURL in PHP language, but the answer of this web service has a long time(13 sec), are any suggestion to speed up web service using?
And i can't use this web service on debain with ngnix web server, can anyone to help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 'prepopulated' Arelle cache folder. If you use documents based on the same taxonomy usually first request is slowest one (when arelle populates his taxonomy files cache)